# Creating a simple python calculation to show in the admin panel on a specific object record

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to python and am working on a new django project and want to display calculations in the admin panel for specific records, using the record data. This would also be replicated on the user interface (which is not built yet).

I have learned the basic storing and manipulating of variables for other calculations made from basic user input. This is a little different as it is done within the admin panel. I am using PyCharm but PyCharm is telling me there are errors. I also used the link here to see if I could get this to work:

https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/6xigr3/how_to_show_calculated_field_in_django_admin/

I realize the code below is not correct, but am also not sure if i'm referencing the variables correctly to access them from within the main function?

How does defining this function change when used in the admin panel vs. the user interface?

Thank you for any help on any questions above!

```
# Create a class to calculate the volume by first converting inches to ft, then to cubic yd
class Volume(models.Model):
    linear_ft = models.DecimalField('Length in feet: ', max_digits=200, decimal_places=2)
    depth_in = models.DecimalField('Depth in inches: ', max_digits=200, decimal_places=2)
    width_in = models.DecimalField('Width in inches: ', max_digits=200, decimal_places=2)

    # Convert inches to feet, store variables for use in future functions
    def in_to_ft(self):
        depth_ft = self.depth_in * 12
        width_ft = self.width_in * 12

    # Call to get cubic yards which uses variables from previous functions
    def get_cu_yd(self):
        dims = str(self.linear_ft) + " length x " + str(self.depth_ft) + " depth x " + str(self.width_ft) + " width")
        cubic_ft = self.linear_ft * self.depth_ft * self.width_ft
        cubic_yd = cubic_ft * 0.037037

        return cubic_yd + "cubic yards: " + str(self.dims)

    # Register the function to the property method
    obj_cu_yd = property(get_cu_yd)

def __str__(self):
    return obj_cu_yd
```

I'd like to take the user input (could be decimals), convert the inches to feet, calculate the cubic feet by multiplying the length (ft) x width (ft) x depth (ft) and store a 'string' version to display the dimensions of the object. The **str**(self) should return the cubic yards and the string describing the object dimensions.

::UPDATE::
I have gotten this far:

```
# Create a class to calculate the volume by first converting inches to ft, then to cubic yd
```

class Volume(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    linear_ft = models.DecimalField('Length in feet: ', max_digits=200, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    depth_in = models.DecimalField('Depth in inches: ', max_digits=200, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    width_in = models.DecimalField('Width in inches: ', max_digits=200, decimal_places=2, default=0)

```
# Create empty variables so not to divide/multiply by nonzero
cubic_ft = 0
cubic_yd = 0

# Set conversion rate from ft to yards
cubic_ft_yd = 0.037037

# Call to get cubic yards
def get_cu_yd(self):
    depth_ft = decimal.Decimal(self.depth_in) * 12
    width_ft = decimal.Decimal(self.width_in) * 12
    dims = str(self.linear_ft) + " length x " + str(depth_ft) + " depth x " + str(width_ft) + " width"
    cubic_ft = decimal.Decimal(self.linear_ft)*depth_ft*width_ft
    cubic_yd = cubic_ft*self.cubic_ft_yd

    return str(self.name) + " - " + str(cubic_yd) + "cubic yards: " + dims

# Register the function to the property method
obj_cu_yd = property(get_cu_yd)
```

def **str**(self):
    return obj_cu_yd

Now my issue is this error: 
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
in reference to the cubic_yd = cubic_ft*self.cubic_ft_yd

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be setting `depth_ft` and `width_ft` like this. You need to set `self.depth_ft = self.depth_in * 12` instead, so that the variable actually gets registered as a member of the instance.

In fact, you shouldn't have that helper function at all.

```py
def get_cu_yd(self):
        depth_ft = self.depth_in * 12
        width_ft = self.width_in * 12
        dims = str(self.linear_ft) + " length x " + str(depth_ft) + " depth x " + str(width_ft) + " width")
        cubic_ft = self.linear_ft * depth_ft * width_ft
        cubic_yd = cubic_ft * 0.037037

        return dims + "cubic yards: " + str(self.dims)
```

Comment: When I do this I get an error: TypeError at /admin/formulas/volume/add/
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'. I think it has something to do with the Volume variables not having a value before the instance is created? For example, do I need to put an empty value before the first record is recorded. I.e. with an empty list or something?

Comment: @AlexanderDing your last comment is incorrect, `self.linear_ft` would give you the value.

Comment: @KevinW you should give your fields `default=0` attributes.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman -- I had to add import decimal, then add decimal.Decimal(self.depth) * 12 (for example, on this line), I had to do it on the others to clear errors. now I have it on the cubic_yd variable and am getting an error: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'